# Wildfly datasource - MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, datasource, wildfly, wildfly-9

Sorry for the basic question. I'm totally new to Wildfly and MongoDB (in fact, I am new to nosql also).

I need to know, is that possible to add MongoDB datasource in wildfly? If yes, then how can I do that?

I have done few tutorials using MySQL and Postgres, it seems like it works very well with those DBs. However, when I tried using MongoDB driver, it's not working as expected.

Comment: take a look at http://www.mastertheboss.com/javaee/mongodb/using-jpa-with-mongodb-and-wildfly

Comment: take a look at this also - https://dzone.com/articles/jboss-eap-7-and-nosql-using-java-ee-and-docker

Answer (score 0):

There is a JDBC driver available for MongoDB from Unity you can download it [here](http://www.unityjdbc.com/mongojdbc/mongo_jdbc.php). Using it should be able to create a Datasource on MangoDB as well as fire standard SQL queries too.

The database class name will be `mongodb.jdbc.MongoDriver` and the database url will be of the format `jdbc:mongo://<serverName>/<databaseName>`